# possible to assign var and use in attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myValue = "sItem-" + val;
$('#something').attr('class','myValue');
```

The DOM show me myValue instead of the value that I set, which I expect to see `sItem-1`. I console.log the myValue, but it can shows sItem-1? hmm...

I also tried `$('#something').attr('class', "sItem-" + val);` I doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are enclosing the variable into single quotes.

Try this

```
$('#something').attr('class',myValue);
```

instead of

```
$('#something').attr('class','myValue');
```

Or even better use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$('#something').prop('class',myValue);
```

Or if you want to add class to an element then you can use `.addClass()`

```
$('#something').addClass(myValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addClass` instead of `attr`: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

And you uses `myValue` with single quotes, that's wrong:

```
$('#something').addClass(myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 var myValue = "sItem-" + val;
 $('#something').addClass('class',myValue);
```